# UIImagePickerController messes up constraint based layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout, uiimagepickercontroller

For part of my storyboard, I have some screens that are meant for editing information about an asset (name, photo, location, etc). So I wanted to use a table with static cells. And I'm trying to use constraint based layouts. In the storyboard editor, I have the following:

[image]

The configurations of my `UITableView` and `UITableViewController` are all default. Below the *Photo* label, is an `UIImageView`. It's constraints are configured as such:

[image]

Basically, it's supposed to be as wide as the cell, and forced to be a square. It's butted up against the bottom of the *Photo* label (which is butted to the top, and centered horizontally). No amount of `Update Frames` in `XCode6` will make it resize as desired in the storyboard. However, when I run the app, on initial open it looks as it should:

[image]

I have an option to update the photo, using an `UIImagePickerController` with code as follows:

```
#pragma mark - Actions
- (IBAction)takePicture {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Camera not Available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion: NULL];
    }
}

#pragma mark - ImagePicker

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (chosenImage) {
        [self updatePhoto: chosenImage];
        self.savePhoto = YES;
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
};
```

After I run this code, regardless of whether I cancel the picker or not, two things happen:

1) The original view gets messed up

[image]

(it squashed the photo view into the 44 pixel standard height cell)

2) The XCode console spewed the following:

```
2014-10-20 15:29:52.715 myValve[5489:1760528] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008cf80 UIImageView:0x1701ea900.width == UIImageView:0x1701ea900.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178292930 UIImageView:0x1701ea900.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x1783868d0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178292c00 V:[UILabel:0x147e60cf0'Photo']-(0)-[UIImageView:0x1701ea900]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1782990a0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x1783868d0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x1701ea900.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1782967b0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x1783868d0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x1701ea900.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178299050 UILabel:0x147e60cf0'Photo'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x1783868d0.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1782934c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1783868d0(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178293650 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1783868d0(43.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008cf80 UIImageView:0x1701ea900.width == UIImageView:0x1701ea900.height>
```

What's going on here? Why can it initially satisfy my constraints, give me no warnings, and show correctly, but after opening and canceling the `UIImagePickerControler`, everything's messed up? Is there some additional support methods I need to implement in my `UITableViewController` subclass?

UPDATE

I decided to probe the constrains of the `contentView` before and after the `UIImagePickerController` has opened. The `constraints` array has the same elements, but one of them changes its value, before:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170285e60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x178381a00(340.5)]>",
```

and after:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170285e60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x178381a00(43.5)]>",
```

The height constraint changes from 43.5 to 340.5. Why?

Comment: It could be that you constraints are being satisfied before heightForRowAtIndexPath: is being called causing the constraint to default to the cell height. 

Do you do a reloadData() call in viewWillAppear? I would try adding [self.view layoutIfNeeded] in your viewWillAppear() method.

Comment: Interesting. I did as you suggest. Now it comes up wrong right away. It's nice that it's now consistent. But I really wanted it laid out with the hoped for height (dynamically sized for the individual static cells, rather than all forced to the same height).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem with a 1:1 ratio photo :(

Comment: I have not yet resolved it.